# How to track a parameter in the Linux kernel efficiently?

Tags: c++, linux, kernel, printk

Recently I wanted to change a kernel code and optimize some parameters. I decided to write the variables into the kernel by using PrintK then reading them by using dmesg. However, I noticed that the performance of the code, which is a scheduler is had been reduced dramatically.

could you please suggest alternative ways to my methods to track the variables?

Thanks a lot

I have tried using printk, but it reduces the performance drastically. As a result, I am looking for a more beneficial way.

Comment: You could expose the values via a virtual file in `/proc` or `/sys`...